# Python - Elbow Chart Issue

Tags: python, k-means

I'm trying to plot a Elbow chart in order to get the ideal number of clusters for that I've this:

```
data = dataset[['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']]
distortions = []
K = range(1, 10)
for k in K:
    kmeanModel = KMeans(n_clusters = k).fit(data)
    kmeanModel.fit(data)
    distortions.append(sum(np.min(cdist(data, kmeanModel.cluster_centers_, 'euclidean'), axis=1)) / data.shape[0])

plt.plot(data, distortions, 'bx-')
plt.xlabel('k')
plt.ylabel('Disortotion')
plt.title('Elbow')
plt.show()
```

When I run this code I'm getting the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 243, in _xy_from_xy
  "have shapes {} and {}".format(x.shape, y.shape))

builtins.ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (122607, 8) and (9,)
```

What is the meaning of this error? How can I solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please include the *complete* error message (i.e. the complete traceback) in the question.  It includes useful information, including the line that generated the error.

Comment: I already add some more useful info about the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `plt.plot(data, distortions, 'bx-')`, you specified `x` to be `data`, which is the original data frame for k-means. It should really be the number of clusters:

```
plt.plot(K, distortions, 'bx-')
plt.xlabel('k')
plt.ylabel('Disortotion')
plt.title('Elbow')
plt.show()
```